# bloom - same version number, different tag

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to re-release  [robot_navigation](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation.git). I have already bloomed the latest version (`0.2.5`) for lunar off of the master branch of the repo.

Melodic however uses the tf2 branch of the repo. I did `catkin_prepare_release -t tf2` which created the `tf20.2.5` (not my best choice of prefix, I'll admit). I also edited the release tag when doing `bloom-release` to be `tf2:{version}`.

However, when it attempts to push the tags to the release repository it fails.

```
==> Pushing tags to release repository for 'robot_navigation'
==> git push --tags
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:locusrobotics/robot_navigation-release.git
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-melodic-costmap-queue_0.2.5-0_bionic -> debian/ros-melodic-costmap-queue_0.2.5-0_bionic
(...snip...)
 * [new tag]         rpm/ros-melodic-robot-navigation-0.2.5-0_28 -> rpm/ros-melodic-robot-navigation-0.2.5-0_28
 ! [rejected]        upstream/0.2.5 -> upstream/0.2.5 (already exists)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:locusrobotics/robot_navigation-release.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.
```

This is presumably because I already pushed the tags with lunar.

What setting do I change to get it to use a different tag here?

(Previously, I used two separate version numbers for the two branches....lunar with `0.2.2` and melodic was `0.2.3`...and `0.2.4`)

- [Release repository](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation-release)
- bloom-release = 0.7.2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315581/bloom---same-version-number,-different-tag/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2019-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hmm. It looks like bloom's release tags don't use the full tag template when creating additional release tags. I believe that change would require a patch to implement and I haven't even begun to consider the side effects of such a change.

I think the two options for expedient resolution would be to use a different version number for the melodic track, which makes sense to me if the sources are divergent; or to use a different release repository so that the tags don't collide.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2019-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2019-02-14**:
That works for me. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing an obvious option.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-02-14**:
Just came here to say, if the content of the source is different, then the version number *must* be different or the package name needs to change. Anything else leads to chaos in my opinion.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2019-02-14**:
So what makes the most sense? I have two versions of this package that I plan to keep updating. I could keep leapfrogging odds/evens....

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2019-02-15**:
Most of the ROS 2 packages that are ported up have given themselves a bunch of version headroom. geometry2 comes to mind, the ros1 release is on 0.6.5 and is at 0.10.1 for ROS 2. If they'll both be supported, perhaps create a new package?